# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004100F)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

so Hi everyone, struggling to solve this almost for a day, i haven't used crystal reports much, so please point me in the right direction.

Here is the problem, we have an asp.net web site using crystal reports. All the reports seems to work fine except one. The Report is opening when it is running in local, but when deployed to the server it is throwing "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004100F)" error.

when i searched for it, it is a logon error, if thats the case it shouldnt work from local either, and other reports using the same connection also working well when deployed in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, currently the report is working, maybe of help to someone else facing the same problem.

In the report database properties, the Locale Identifier of the connection was set to 17417 which is English-Malaysia(dont know why and how), i changed the connection Locale Identifier to 1033 English-United States and now it is working in the server.

Database -> Set Datasource Location -> report -> properties -> Locale Identifer

If someone could reply how the locale identifier got set to 17417, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [SAP](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1877169):

If it's only certain reports, the compare the reports:

Connection type (OLE DB, ODBC, etc.).

Is it reports with subreports only? If so, check the above and log on to the subreports.

Check other differences. parameters? Tables vs. Stored Proc, etc., etc.

You may also want to troubleshoot by trying out the 32 bit runtime

Comment: connection type same between reports.. all params and storeprocs checked.. still have no idea..

Answer (score 0):

Roy, I believe you set local identifier when you create database connection. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKI1d.png)

Comment: we didnt set it explicitly, it got auto set when we created it. what i wish to understand is that from where this metadata is coming from.