# How to launch in c# a Crystal Report with a subreport with Webservice datasource

Tags: c#, web-services, crystal-reports

I have designed a report with a subreport in witch the datasource is a webservice call (without authentication).
In Crystal Report designer the report works fine and it preview the data normally.

The problem is when I try to launch it in c#: I receive an Exception: COMException (0x800002CD)

I assign in c# the logonInfo to the main report like this:

```
    foreach (Table tbl in rpt.Database.Tables)
    {
        logOnInfo = tbl.LogOnInfo;
        connInfo = logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;
        connInfo.UserID = connInfo.UserID;
        connInfo.Password = GetMyPassword(connInfo.DatabaseName, connInfo.UserID);
        tbl.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connInfo;
        tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
        tbl.Location = tbl.Location;
    }
```

If I launch the report without the subreport, then it works fine and the report is displayed. But if I launch the report with the webservice subreport, then I receive an Exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800002CD): Error in file Subreport1 17300_23640_{4D26153A-BD4D-4482-A2AB-0FA4435F7571}.rpt:
The information from the database could not be loaded.
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.SetTableLocation(ISCRTable CurTable, ISCRTable NewTable)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.set_Location(String value)
   at SampleSubreportWS.frmReportPreview..ctor(Action reportPrinted, String filename) 
   at C:\..\SampleSubreportWS\frmReportPreview.cs:line 56
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try setting the ApplyLogOnInfo for subreports too in your code. See these links for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499325/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x8004100f; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709438/how-to-stop-crystal-report-viewer-from-asking-login-credentials-when-opening-sub

Comment: None of those example links apply to this case.